# Old Cygwin packages usable with version 1.7?

Tags: cygwin

Are "old" Cygwin packages usable with version 1.7?
I mean packages used with version 1.5.

Said differently: do all package authors need to rewrite all of their sources (that worked OK with v1.5) for Cygwin v1.7? (hope not!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Cygwin 1.7 is backward compatible with 1.5, i.e. programs built on Cygwin 1.5 should still run on 1.7. In fact quite a lot of packages in the Cygwin 1.7 distribution are still the same as in 1.5.

Answer (score -1):

You need to recompile for `cygwin 1.7` since ABI (and API) has changed.

Comment: Incorrect. While the API is continuously extended, a lot of thought goes into maintaining backward compatibility.

Comment: Yep you are right 1.5 apps works on 1.7 but not vice versa, my bad!